# SharePoint rest api not bringing items from List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I tried to use Rest API to get list items in Office 365, the list has 3 items in total.

When I visit the below URL:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/
```

It shows list information, but in the item count it has 0. These 3 items are there in the list for more than a week now. Rest API is working fine for other list items in the same site.

Answer (score 4):

To get the list items using REST API you need to use the URL like below:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items
```

To get the List Item Count using REST API you need to use:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')?$select=ItemCount
```

**Reference**:
[Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

Comment: Hi Vignesh, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily. It also removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Should append items endpoint in the url, please check the official documentation as below:

[image]

[Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)