# Web part list items count

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, count

I have a list built using web part. I want count of that web part list.

**Scenario:**

I have List A. Created list B and added web part into it which points to list A.

I want list item count of list B.

I used `'/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list B')/items'`. But I am getting 0 as count though there are many items.

I don't want to return count of list A. So is there any approach to get count of web part list?

**Code**

```
function GetWebPartPageItems(ListName)
{
$.ajax({  
url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List B')?$select=ItemCount",
    type: "GET",  
    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
    },  
async:false,
    success: function(data) {  
        console.log(data.d.results);  
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
});  
}
```

When url is hit in browser,I get resopnse as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry 
xml:base="http://sharepoint.brainvire.com/sites/DMS/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:etag="&quot;40&quot;"><id>http://sharepoint.brainvire.com/sites/DMS/_api/Web/Lists(guid'514f92fb-ccd7-497c-81b9-b74fc074ee37')</id><category term="SP.List" 
scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link 
rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'514f92fb-ccd7-497c-81b9-b74fc074ee37')" /><title />
<updated>2019-08-05T10:34:16Z</updated><author><name /></author>
<content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:ItemCount m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:ItemCount>
</m:properties></content></entry>
```

In list,items are present:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting this `Created list B and added web part into it which points to list A`. Can you please add some details about it?

Comment: I created list B.Then added web part into it(Edit page-->add web part).Then in categories section,I selected Apps.In Apps category,under part section,I selected list A.

Answer (score 1):

To get the List Item Count using REST API you need to use:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')?$select=ItemCount
```

Where `List Name` is display name of your list (Not the list name in URL).

For more clarification check my answer given in below link:

[SharePoint rest api not bringing items from List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264390/sharepoint-rest-api-not-bringing-items-from-list/264391#264391)

**Update**:

From Image attached to your question, it seams that the display name of your list is "Pending For Approval". So try using below URL to get the item count:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pending For Approval')?$select=ItemCount
```

Comment: It is working if I use same link in browser but implementing same in javascript does not give desired result.

Comment: Can you please add your complete Javascript code to your question?

Comment: There is an edit in my answer.It is working neither in javascript nor in browser.

Comment: What is the error you are getting while you hit this URL in browser?

Comment: I am not getting any error.I am getting some xml syntax response.

Comment: In XML try finding(Ctrl + F) `ItemCount`. You should get something like `<m:properties><d:ItemCount m:type="Edm.Int32">7</d:ItemCount>`. Where **7** is item count.

Comment: I am getting as 0.I have added response in my question.

Comment: Are you sure you have items in the list on which you are trying this REST call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97048/discussion-between-user85213-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Yes,there are items

Comment: can we have filter on column using query <siteurl>/sites/DMS/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list A')?$select=ItemCount

Comment: Try using URL in updated answer with correct name of your list.

Comment: I am doing same but I am getting 0 as count. As list has been added as web part,is it causing a problem?